# Wireless won't connect properly, keeps asking for a network key

Tags: wireless

I have double and triple checked my network key and it is correct but I just can't connect to my wireless network.  I was having troubles with my wireless driver but found a solution for that on here, now I'm hoping someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on the network icon and choose edit connections...

Then under the wireless tab find your network and delete it.
Scan and try adding again.